# Using programmatic element ids in EL

Tags: jsp, dom, jstl, el

I'm trying to get an element with a programmatically constructed id using EL in JSP. These ids follow the pattern `table_1, table_2, table_3`, etc. Earlier versions without the generated ids got them via `${table_a}, ${table_b}`, etc. Now I'm trying to use `${table_${num}}`, but that isn't working. Does anyone know how to do this?

Other things I've tried have been `${parent_element.children().get(0)}` to sidestep having to use the id, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Clarification: I have a series of elements with ids `table_1, table_2, table_3`, etc. I need to get the elements themselves. You would normally do this with `${table_1}, ${table_2}, ${table_3}`, but I'm trying to find a programmatic way to do it.

Comment: "${table}_${num}"? It's not completely clear what your requirements actually are.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have a series of elements with ids table_1, table_2, table_3, etc. I need to get the elements themselves. You would normally do this with ${table_1}, ${table_2}, ${table_3}, but I'm trying to find a programmatic way to do it.

Comment: In what context are you trying to get them? Without any context it's difficult to understand what the issue is.